# Difference between starting an application and starting a managed server in weblogic server?

Tags: deployment

I wanted to know what is the difference between starting an application and starting a managed server in weblogic server?
I have 5 different applications targeted to one managed server, whenever I make any change to any one application I have to restart the managed server entirely to make the changes to reflect. Why is it not that when I simply start and stop the application alone from Deployments it reflects, why do I need to start the managed server every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the managed server will restart the entire JVM including all installed EAR files. Stopping an application simply puts the application in Admin mode so the application class files are not unloaded.

This following document discusses various methods for redeploying applications in WebLogic based on the scope of the deployment:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/redeploy.htm#DEPGD258